# After sharing a post on Facebook using ShareDialog my application is not redirected, control comes to Facebook Newsfeed immediately

Tags: android, android-facebook

Here is some sample code which I have used:

And the problem arises **for marshmello and above**

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle(mInviteFriendsInfo.__facebook.__title)
                        .setContentDescription(mInviteFriendsInfo.__facebook.__desc)
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(mInviteFriendsInfo.__facebook.__shareUrl))
                        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(mInviteFriendsInfo.__facebook.__image))
                        .build();

                shareDialog.show(linkContent, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
            }
```